# dnn How to reset passwords for users by createdate

Tags: passwords, dotnetnuke, reset

I had imported users from my old database, while importing users i had specified a default password for all users.

Now I want to notify users about their login details and want to reset password to a random password.

I want to reset password only for those users, which I created on that date.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that with DNN out of the box.  I've seen a few options for what you are trying to do:

1. Create your own DNN Module that could cycle through selected users and reset their password.  I actually did this a while ago for a previous company.
2. Their is a bulk user management Module on the DNN Store which does what you are asking: http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/dnnmasters-user-manager-suite-42